# WooCommerce video products

Tags: wordpress, video, woocommerce, product

I have a WordPress website that uses WooCommerce to sell video products. Each video links to a product description page:

- If the user is logged in and has bought the video he must be able to view it on his dashboard.
- If the user is not logged in and has not bought the video, the user must be directed to the registration page.

I have no idea how to achieve this. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: You could use WooCommerce Memberships plugin with  WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin…

Comment: To expand on what @LoicTheAztec commented you can find the [WooCommerce Memberships plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-memberships/) here. However, it is not free. As of today it is $150 for a single site